# Unity RegisterInstance of IDisposable objects

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, idisposable, unity2.0

Unity 2.0:

By default RegisterInstance uses the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager. When the Unity container is disposed, it calls Dispose on the instance (if IDisposable).

In my case that's not what I want. The instance is owned by and disposed by another class; Unity should just inject the reference. So I used:

```
container.RegisterInstance(instance, new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager());
```

The Unity documentation (under Understanding Lifetime Managers) states:

> Using the RegisterInstance method to
>   register an existing object results in
>   the same behavior as if you just
>   registered the lifetime container with
>   RegisterType. Therefore, it is
>   recommended that you do not use the
>   RegisterInstance method to register an
>   existing object when using the
>   non-default lifetime managers except
>   for the thread in which the
>   RegisterInstance was invoked.

What does this mean?

The same section also states:

> If you registered an existing instance
>   of an object using the
>   RegisterInstance method, the container
>   returns the same instance for all
>   calls to Resolve or ResolveAll or when
>   the dependency mechanism injects
>   instances into other classes, provided
>   that one of the following is true:
>
> - You have specified a container-controlled lifetime manager
> - You have used the default lifetime manager
> - You are resolving in the same context in which you registered the
>     instance when using a different
>     lifetime manager.

I tried resolving in a different thread after using RegisterInstance with ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager, and it worked - I got the singleton instance.

My code matches an example in the Creating Instance Registrations section. I want to make sure I understand the context caveats, though.

To be clear, I always want the Unity container to inject the instance I registered regardless of thread, etc. and I do **not** want Unity to dispose of it. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129789/unity-2-0-and-handling-idisposable-types-especially-with-perthreadlifetimemanage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are good. All the per-thread comments only matters when you are using PerThreadLifetimeManager, which you are not using. It's just clumsy wording on the MSDN article part.

This is not a standard terminology, but in this article by context they mean something defined by a particular life time manager. For PerThreadLifetimeManager your context is your thread. For HierarchicalLifetimeManager your context is a particular container in your container hierarchy.

For ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager there is no particular context, so you can ignore the note in question completely.

As a side note, make sure that you don't dispose your instances while you still expect the container to resolve them. If you do, your resolve request will either return a different instance than you expected, or throw an exception, depending on whether the container can construct your type or not.

Answer (score 5):

Be aware of `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager`. You must still hold the reference to the instance somewhere outside of the container. Once you lose the reference you can lose the instance because `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` holds only `WeakReference`. If you don't have normal reference Garbage collector can collect your instance. Check [example](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/) on my blog.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. @zespri addressed my question specifically, but your blog entry is excellent.