# Using Unity, how do you automatically dispose an IDisposable?

Tags: entity-framework, inversion-of-control, unity-container, unit-of-work

How do you automatically dispose a class that implements `IDisposable` that was newed through DI using Unity as the IoC?

For example, say I have an MVC application with the following layers:

1. MVC
2. Service
3. Repository (Entity Framework that implements Unit of Work pattern for CRUD operations)

A `UnitOfWork` class within the repository layer implements the `IDisposable` interface and is injected into the service layer using DI via Unity.  Unless I am missing something, without automatically disposing the `UnitOfWork` class you would need to override the `Dispose()` method on the controller that called the service (which also needs to implement `IDisposable`), and bubble up through the stack until you reached the `Dispose()` method on the `UnitOfWork` (or the respective repository if you weren't using the Unit of Work pattern).

e.g.

```
// controller
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_serviceLayer != null)
    {
        _serviceLayer.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

// service layer
public override Dispose() {
    if (_uow != null)
    {
        _uow.Dispose();
    }
}

// unit of work
public void Dispose() {
    if (_context != null)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129789/unity-2-0-and-handling-idisposable-types-especially-with-perthreadlifetimemanag) suggests it’s not supported? "*There are only a few circumstances where Unity will dispose an instance. It is really unsupported*" Is this still true with Unity 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/)'s PerRequestLifetimeManager then at the end of the HTTP request the UnityPerRequestHttpModule will dispose of all objects registered with a PerRequestLifetimeManager that implement IDisposable.

Comment: I am unable get the dispose method to fire when using a simple interface and implementation that both implement IDisposable, combined with PerRequestLifetimeManager when registering the type. Does this still work?